# EventListener to determine when data-src changes to src

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been messing with a piece of code for some time now, and I can't seem to properly determine when `data-src` changes to `src` - So I want to see if I can hook a EventListener to an element and see if we can properly determine it then.

So let's say that I have the following element `let iframe = videoWrapper.html(videoElement).children('iframe');` which gives me:
[image]

Which renders like this:
[image]

**Please note**: A third-party implementation changes the `data-src` to `src` dynamically based on various actions.

**Question**:
What is the best approach to take to check when the `data-src` has switched over to `src` and then execute conditionals/methods? I'd like to hook a event listener to determine that, but I don't know which one would be the right approach.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Please include your code, not pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MutationObserver
The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree. It is designed as a replacement for the older Mutation Events feature, which was part of the DOM3 Events specification.
[Read more...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Thank you! Can this properly determine when `data-src` attribute changes to `src` for a specific element?

Comment: Sure, just read These Mozilla docs and it will solve your problem for forever :)